# legacy code uses of .or

Tags: fortran

In older fortran code, when `.or.` is used with two integer types, is the result a bit-wise or of the operands or 0/1?

I'm updating legacy code, and believe I should be replacing these instances of `.or.` with `IOR`, but am uncertain if that was the expected result in older code.  Should I instead be setting the result to either 0 or 1?

Comment: Just for my curiosity, which compiler accepts that?

Comment: @vladimirF I wish I knew!  I'm certain my job would be easier if I were able to compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you are seeing is indeed a custom extension.  I haven't seen this one in use before, but I did find a reference on the web about such things actually existing in the wild:

> When Fortran programs communicate directly with digital hardware it may be necessary to carry out bit-wise logical operations on bit-patterns. Standard Fortran does not provide any direct way of doing this, since logical variables essentially only store one bit of information and integer variables can only be used for arithmetic. Many systems provide, as an extension, intrinsic functions to perform bit-wise operations on integers. The function names vary: typically they are IAND, IOR, ISHIFT. **A few systems provide allow the normal logical operators such as .AND. and .OR. to be used with integer arguments**: this is a much more radical extension and much less satisfactory, not only because it reduces portability, but also reduces the ability of the compiler to detect errors in normal arithmetic expressions.

[Reference](http://www.star.le.ac.uk/~cgp/prof77.html#tth_sEc6.1)

Comment: I wish I didn't learn about this ugly extension, but +1 for this excavation

Answer (score 1):

Compilers with DEC/VMS links or heritage support the extension of allowing integer arguments to .OR. (and other logical operators).  That group of compilers define the .OR. operation on integers as being bit wise.

A currently supported compiler with that heritage is Intel Fortran (via Compaq Fortran, via Digital Fortran, etc).

Comment: Yes, and that discussion comp.lang.fortran also mentions that it can be enabled in IBM XL Fortran.